# how can I get installed python packages in code

Tags: python, pip

Is there any way to get list of installed python packages in the environment?
I tried executing pip command in code but is there any api for interacting with packages?

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system("pip freeze")
```

Comment: @SaiSreenivas it seems it relies on pydoc to do this. And it actually imports all the modules, so there is a risk of side-effects.

Answer (score 1):

Type `help("modules")` in the Python shell. That will print out all the modules you have installed on your computer.

Comment: @Glyphhack, if the answer is correct, mark it as correct by clicking on that gray tick.